# Is it possible to Debug iOS app on Windows/Linux?

Tags: ios, windows, ubuntu, debugging, mobile-application

is there a way how to debug an iOS mobile app on Windows or Linux (Ubuntu)?

I have an application which runs fine on Android, but it has some flaws on iOS. For Android debugging, I always used the Chrome device inspector and I am wondering if it’s possible for iOS too?

The Webkit Adapter I found (https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) works for debugging websites opened on iPhone via SAFARI browser, but not for the mobile app. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop your own lldb to support debugging non-jailbroken iOS device on Window, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf9om.png)